# Vue, что происходит под капотом работы при декларативном рендеринге?

Tags: vue.js

```
<div id="app">
  {{ message }}
</div>

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Привет, Vue!'
  }
})
```

Понятно что создаём объект, монтируем в DOM node. А что дальше происходит?
Шаблонизатор работает?

Comment: [исходники открыты](https://github.com/vuejs/vue) можно отлаживать. [Справка тоже есть](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/) - возможно стоит конкретизировать вопрос